# iTextSharp-LGPL.4.1.6: XMLWorkerHelper does not exist in current context

Tags: pdf, itext

Below is my sample code to download pdf using iTextSharp 4.1.6

```
string GridHtml = "<p>Hello and welcome</p>";
        using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(GridHtml);
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "Sample.pdf");
        }
```

on the following line `XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);` I am getting

> XMLWorkerHelper does not exist in current context

Error

how can I download pdf in 4.1.6 version in iTextSharp

Comment: AFAIK the XMLWorker has been introduced during the early 5.x versions, so it's not contained in version 4.1.6. You may try the HTMLWorker, the much simpler precursor. It might suffice for your needs.

Comment: To give a complete overview in conjunction with @mkl answer, iText 7 has the much improved pdfHTML add-on. Also more on the history of XMLWorker and HTMLWorker [here](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-converting-html-to-pdf-with-pdfhtml)